# mod_rewrite on certain REQUEST_URI

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a file structure like this:

```
ROOT
|----app/
|----app/init.php
|----public/
|----public/index.php
|----public/img/
|----public/js/
|----.htaccess
```

The `.htaccess`'s rules will redirect all `REQUEST_URI` to `app/init.php`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|ttf|woff|woff2|eot|otf|svg|png|jpg)$
RewriteCond public/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond public/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ app/init.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

Then `app/init.php` will use `require_once` to get the appropriate `.html/.php` in the `public` folder.

This works fine; all excluded file in `.htaccess` will be called as such `public/...` pattern of path in `public/index.php`.

For examples:

1. CSS `<link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/layout.css">`
2. Image `<img src="public/img/abc.jpg" alt="">`

However, I don't want to add `public/` prefix on all the file I excluded in `.htaccess`

I tried adding

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpg)$
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ public/$1 [NC]
```

However, it does not work. More accurately, when I called like this `img/abc.jpg` in `public/index.php` file, it feeds back is 500 (Internal Server Error). I am guessing it is something wrong with the redirection, but I am not sure.

**Question:** How can I call `css` or `img` or etc.. those file without a prefix of `public/` in the path?

Comment: I finally only redirect `.php` to `init.php` page so I dont need to care what others do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have it this way in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# handle css, js and img files
RewriteRule (?:^|/)((?:img|css|js)/.+) public/$1 [L,NC]

# handle rest of the files
RewriteCond public/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond public/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !^public/ app/init.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Im fairly new to regex,  so please bear woth me...what does the `?:` do ??  and wont the L flag on the first rewrite stop any rewrite afterwards ??  I will take it into test asap,  thanks btw !

Comment: `(?:..)` is called a **non-capturing group** in regex. `L` flag doesn't stop other rules, it just continued mod_rewrite loop. btw did it work?

Comment: Sorry for the late response..with the `RewriteBase`, it somehow leads to a 404, and `RewriteRule` for css, js and img is partly working, the css is shown as `Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html`

Comment: I have messed around a bit, and this `RewriteRule` seems to interpret correctly, heres the `RewriteRule` that I found `RewriteCond public/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} (img|css|js)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ public/$1 [NC]`

Comment: Is there something that I can improve or take aware of ?? thanks for your help once again!

Comment: it works great, thanks! I tested a bit, it seems now the file calls is both success whether with or without the prefix of `public/`, is this normal ? and is there side note that I need to take aware of?

Comment: it actually generates a 404 on `css` and `img` if absolute path is used in this case..

Comment: ok apparently you're not using this in `DocumentRoot`. I have rolled back my changes.

Comment: I will keep the previous version one :) I guess my structure is a bit weird